# Changes to "Language & Text" preferences won't stick

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, system-preferences

I can't get my changes to "Language & Text" preferences to 'stick'.

I've tried deleting or changing abbreviations and setting everything back to default. Every time I log out they change back again.

Must be a privileges problem right? Does anyone know where to find the settings file so I can delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was suggested that i post this as an answer so here goes :

when i checked
~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist i found the file had somehow become locked. maybe migration assistant was the culprit, as i had fairly recently moved to a different machine. unlocking the file enabled changes to be saved.

thanks everyone for the help!